# Is it possible to merge unrelated histories in gitgraph.js?

Tags: gitgraph.js

I would like to document using with a `gitgraph.js`-generated pictogram a commit history showing two unrelated projects merged together, such as the following graph:

```
* f105303 (HEAD -> master) Work on combined project
*   32a6a9f Merge branch 'B'
|\
| * d1731c8 (B) Work on project B
| * 2496c08 Start of project B
* 0dcae66 Work on project A
* fe6f8d9 Start of project A
```

I cannot find from the documentation how to create more than one root commit. Is it possible? How?

Here is a codepen showing what I tried unsuccessfully:

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/drok-the-scripter/pen/RwEqpVp)